# .Net unauthorized access exception after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, iis-7.5

I deployed my internal web application to server A and got an error when creating a file to a network drive on server B. If I run locally, the file got created on server B successfully.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\b\folder\test.pdf' is denied.

The identity of the application pool is networkservice. And I gave networkservice full control on the destination folder on server B. I even gave `Everyone` full control, but it still got the error.

Server A runs .NET 7.5. Code to create file:

```
var byteArray = generateArray();
var destination = "\\\\b\\folder\\test.pdf";
try {
    var destinationFile = new FileInfo(destination);
    if (destinationFile.Exists) {
        destinationFile.Delete();
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destination, byteArray);
} catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
    //
}
```

I've seen someone got the exact same problem [here](http://ask.webatall.com/iis/18508_access-to-the-path-is-denied.html). But it didn't solve mine.

**Solution:**
I changed the identity to administrator account instead of using `network service` for the application pool. It works but I don't fully understand why it works. Because the network service on A is different than the one on B?

Comment: Have you tried to impersonate a user or administrator of server B?

Comment: `Network Service` is unique to each server, so the `Network Service` on one machine is different from the one on another machine.  However, that's beside the point.  `Network Service` is actually doing something completely different.  When the app pool runs as `Network Service` it actually authenticates against the *machine name* in the Active Directory authentication.  So if your machine is named `WEB1`, then it authenticates against `$WEB1`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you provided access to everyone, certain applications have to receive specific permission.  This was apart of the UAC System introduced in Window's Vista.  This move was to increase security, so an application couldn't run under any user and basically have full access.

What you should do, is on the directory provide the following access:

```
IIS AppPool\NameOfAppPool
```

That will provide specific access to your hosted web application to that directory, for IIS will be able to correctly manipulate the directory.  Some code you could implement to help validate before you write or read, would be:

```
public static bool ValidateIOPermission(string path)
{
     try
     {
          if(Directory.Exist(path))
               return true;

          else { Directory.CreateDirectory(path); }
     }

     catch(Exception ex) { return false; }
}
```

The above code is a small sample, basically try to perform the action and catch the exception, that way you know if you have access or not.